# How to set date format in import Laravel Excel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im have small problem
I need to import to DB a Excel file with a lot of information
In my Excel file im have row with date format like this YYYY-MM-DD
When import complete Instead of this date format YYYY-MM-DD im get a value of random numbers
I  tried to changed type of row in DB, Encoding of DB but this is not help
MB somebody know what im do wrong
This is my code from import file

```
public function model(array $row)
{
    return new ImportPassportCounter([
        'OS_RAH' => $row[0],
        'N_MARK' => $row[1],
        'ZAV_NOMER' => $row[2],
        'DIAM' => $row[3],
        'N_MISK' => $row[4],
        'DATA_VST' => \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', "$row[5]"),
        'DATA_POV' => $row[6],
        'DATA_NAST_POV' => $row[7],
        'KIL_MISIAC' => $row[8],
        'POP_POK' => $row[9],
        'OST_POK' => $row[10],
        'TIP' => $row[11],
        'KON_POK' => $row[12],
        'DATA_KON_POK' => $row[13],
        'DATA_N_PLOMB' => $row[14],
        'N_PLOMB' => $row[15],
    ]);
}
```

And this is my migration file

```
Schema::create('import_passport_counters', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('OS_RAH')->nullable();
        $table->string('N_MARK')->nullable();
        $table->string('ZAV_NOMER')->nullable();
        $table->string('DIAM')->nullable();
        $table->string('N_MISK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_VST')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_POV')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_NAST_POV')->nullable();
        $table->string('KIL_MISIAC')->nullable();
        $table->string('POP_POK')->nullable();
        $table->string('OST_POK')->nullable();
        $table->string('TIP')->nullable();
        $table->string('KON_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_KON_POK')->nullable();
        $table->text('DATA_N_PLOMB')->nullable();
        $table->string('N_PLOMB')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using Carbon, like below

```
\Carbon::parse($row[5])->toDateString();
```

Comment: Nice try man but im try used this method before
And im have this errro
Could not parse 'DATA_VST': DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (DATA_VST) at position 0 (D): The timezone could not be found in the database

Comment: You can try "Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '1999-01-24')->toDateTimeString()" instead of the above one